# Exporting an empty's animation from Blender to After Effects?

Tags: export, transforms

Anyone know how to get an Empty's transform animation to After Effects? The intention is that I want to parent a Trapcode particular (particle plug-in)'s emitter to this empty.

Comment: Since Blender's data model and Python API are well-documented, and pretty much any known file format can be written, the question is more "what kind of data can After Effects read?".

Comment: There is an export addon that comes with blender. Did you already tried that?